# Play! Framework returns empty header for websocket connection if request comes through nginx

Tags: nginx, playframework, websocket, playframework-2.1

I'm using Nginx 1.3.7 and Play! Framework 2.1 and I need to proxy my HTTP-, HTTPS- and WebSocket-connections to the Play! server through nginx.

I rely on the websocket proxy feature of the nginx trunk and I did set the "upgrade" and "connection" headers to correctly forward the headers for the websocket connections (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html):

```
 map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
   default Upgrade;
   ''      close;
 }

 location / {
   proxy_pass  http://my-backend;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
 }
```

I made sure that Play! get's the correct headers during the websocket initialization. The request.headers object in Play! looks exactly the same with our without nginx.

```
Map(
  Cache-Control -> Buffer(no-cache),
  Connection -> Buffer(Upgrade),
  Host -> Buffer(my-backend),
  Origin -> Buffer(https://my-host:8443),
  Pragma -> Buffer(no-cache),
  Sec-WebSocket-Extensions -> Buffer(x-webkit-deflate-frame),
  Sec-WebSocket-Key -> Buffer(nk5JVO4I5QRMQnSxAJaRCg==),
  Sec-WebSocket-Version -> Buffer(13),
  Upgrade -> Buffer(websocket)
)
```

Here is the problem: In case the request comes from nginx the response from Play! is empty and doesn't contain any headers, just the protocol-version: "HTTP/1.1 0 ".
Correctly the response from Play! would look like that:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: YHVb1xdsVqaObgQxqksBQPhdkvc=
Upgrade: websocket
```

Comment: It seems nginx drops the "Connection: Upgrade" it is getting from the Play! server and instead fills in "Connection: keep-alive", which let's the websocket connection fail. see for http headers-> http://p.ngx.cc/170e3fa233b4e3a4

Comment: Isn't http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html saying websocket available from 1.3.13?

Comment: Nginx 1.3.7 does not support websockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, the solution is of course to use right version of nginx. 1.3.7 fails to forward the "Connection: Upgrade" flag, because the feature was only introduced in nginx 1.3.13.

I recommend using the latest dev/trunk version.